# Mysql rank with join table, result not true

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 table name table 'hasil' and table 'kat_soal' to join and give rank on each 'KatID' field on 'hasil' table..

here is my hasil table :

```
HasilID  KatID  UserID  JBenar  JSalah  Nilai

15       1      1000    2       1       66.66666666666666
16       3      1000    2       0       100
17       1      1001    1       2       33.33333333333333
18       3      1001    1       1       50
19       1      1002    3       0       90
20       3      1002    2       0       80
```

and there is my kat_soal table

```
KatID Kategori          Lama
1     IPA               30
2     IPS               30
3     Matematika        30
4     Bahasa Indonesia  20
5     Bahasa Inggris    20
```

this my query generate rank:

```
SELECT a.KatID,a.UserID,b.Kategori,c.Nama,a.JBenar,a.JSalah,ROUND(a.Nilai,2) as Nilai,
    FIND_IN_SET( a.Nilai, l.list) AS rank
      from hasil a
      JOIN kat_soal b
      ON a.KatID = b.KatID 
    JOIN  datauser c
    ON a.UserID=c.UserID
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( a2.Nilai ORDER BY a2.Nilai DESC ) as list
    FROM hasil a2) l 
WHERE a.KatID='1'
ORDER BY a.Nilai DESC;
```

my result

```
//FOR KatID=1
KatID   UserID   Kategori   Nama    JBenar   JSalah   Nilai  rank
1       1002     IPA        ratam   3        0        90.00  2
1       1000     IPA        Tarsan  2        1        66.67  4
1       1001     IPA        wisnu   1        2        33.33  6

//FOR KatID=3
3       1000    Matematika  Tarsan  2        0        100.00 1
3       1002    Matematika  ratam   2        0        80.00  3
3       1001    Matematika  wisnu   1        1        50.00  5
```

My Expected Result

```
//FOR KatID=1
KatID   UserID   Kategori   Nama    JBenar   JSalah   Nilai  rank
1       1002     IPA        ratam   3        0        90.00  1
1       1000     IPA        Tarsan  2        1        66.67  2
1       1001     IPA        wisnu   1        2        33.33  3

//FOR KatID=3
3       1000    Matematika  Tarsan  2        0        100.00 1
3       1002    Matematika  ratam   2        0        80.00  2
3       1001    Matematika  wisnu   1        1        50.00  3
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Which database are you actually using?  I'm guessing MySQL because otherwise you'd already have `ROW_NUMBER()` available.

Comment: yes I using MySQL DB @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: You can [simulate row number](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) in MySQL by using a session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good example to solve the issue is by looking at: http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results .

You are making this a bit complicated: First You take the value, making the value a string, then "finding position in string".

From the example it should be completely ok if it is done as *(untested)*:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT a.KatID,a.UserID,b.Kategori,c.Nama,a.JBenar,a.JSalah,ROUND(a.Nilai,2) as Nilai,
@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
  from hasil a
  JOIN kat_soal b
  ON a.KatID = b.KatID 
JOIN  datauser c
ON a.UserID=c.UserID
WHERE a.KatID='1'
ORDER BY rank;
```

**EDIT:** Changed ordering - You are expecting to by ordered by rank in the final.

Below is the script without using table `datauser` for any1 to test:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT a.KatID,a.UserID,b.Kategori,a.JBenar,a.JSalah,ROUND(a.Nilai,2) as Nilai,
@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
  from hasil a
  JOIN kat_soal b
  ON a.KatID = b.KatID 
WHERE a.KatID='1'
ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: Wow, Thx bro that's work for me
i used my script to previous table, but my script not work to this table lol,
btw, thank's for help bro :)